# How to extract this data using Jsoup?

Tags: android, json, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

From example I want to grab **name1, name2, name3, and name4** from the following HTML code.

```
<td width="200"><a>name1</a></td>
<td width="200">name2 </td>
<td width="200"><a>name3</a></td>
<td width="200">name4 </td>
```

Now If you notice **name1, and name3** are in tag **a**, however **name2, and name4** are in tag **td**. I used two separate codes to grab the names, but it is inefficient and slow. The above HTML code is only a portion of the real code.

```
try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://somesite.com").get();

                // Here to get the names inside tag a
                Elements links = doc.select("td a");
                for (Element el : links) {

                    linkText = el.ownText();

                    arr_linkText.add(linkText);
                    }

                //Here to get the names inside tag td
                Elements linktwo = doc.select("td");
                    for (Element eltwo : linktwo) {

                        linkText = eltwo.ownText();

                        arr_linkText.add(linkText);
                        }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My question is **How do I grab the names faster than this method?** Maybe one code for both.

Thank You!

Comment: I hope someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the `text`,

```
    Elements list = doc.select("td[width=200]");
    for(Element td: list) {
        System.out.println(td.text());
    }
```

Comment: This only grabs name2 and name3.

Comment: I execute and it prints all. You'd better show your code and your input HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ',' (comma) operator as an "OR", which is what you want to do here. So try doing something like this:

```
try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://somesite.com").get();

      Elements links = doc.select("td, td a");
      for (Element el : links) {
            arr_linkText.add(el.text());
      }
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```